# How to have mongodb decode struct passed into function

Tags: mongodb, go

The `Decode` step of the following code does not populate the original `document` object correctly. It overwrites it with a `bson` object.

```
func main() {
    c := Call{}
    dbGetObject("collection", &c)
}

func dbGetObject(collectionName string, document interface{}) (err error) {
    uri, creds, auth := dbGetAuth()

    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetAuth(creds)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(context.TODO())

    collection := client.Database(auth.Database).Collection(collectionName)

    err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"number": "12345"}).Decode(&document)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Yet the following code does work properly:

```
func dbGetObject(collectionName string) (err error) {
    uri, creds, auth := dbGetAuth()

    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetAuth(creds)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(context.TODO())

    collection := client.Database(auth.Database).Collection(collectionName)

    c := Call{}
    err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"number": "12345"}).Decode(&c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The only difference being that the instance of the struct is passed into the function vs instantiated in the `dbGetObject` function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized what is going on. In the call to the function and then to Decode I am passing a pointer. So, it's actually passing a pointer to a pointer into the Decode call. So the fix is to change the decode call from:

```
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"number": "12345"}).Decode(&document)
```

to

```
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"number": "12345"}).Decode(document)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the type of document is `interface`.
if you fix the argument type as below, it will work correctly.

```
func dbGetObject(collectionName string, document *Call)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am intentionally passing it as an interface because I will be calling it with different types of structs. However, I just realized what was going on. I was ultimately passing a pointer to a pointer into the `Decode` call.